# Chrome timeout problem with animation

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, settimeout

I've written a simple Slider in jQuery with autplay. If autoplay is enabled a setTimeout is set that points to a function. This function then has a recursive setTimeout to itself.

All works well, except in Chrome. After I've changed a tab, wait for a while and return, the slider is freaking out. It looks like there are multiple instances of the timeout active... but that cannot be the case since I appoint the timeout to the same variable.

Some relevant code:

```
var timer;

  function autoplay() {
    currentPosition++;
    if(currentPosition == numberOfSlides) {
      // last slide
      currentPosition = 0;  
    }
    manageNavigation(currentPosition);

    // Hide / show controls
    manageControls(currentPosition);

    // animate the slides
    slideshowAnimate();  

    // set timer
    if(autoplay_enable) {
      //clearTimeout(timer);
      timer = setTimeout(function() { autoplay() }, interval*1000)     
     }
   }
  function setTimer() { 
    if(autoplay_enable) {
      timer = setTimeout(function() { autoplay() }, interval*1000)     
    }
  }

  setTimer();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, resetting the value of `timer` will not cancel the current timer.  For that you need to `clearTimeout`.  All timer holds is a numeric reference to the timer, not a closure or anything of that nature.

Assuming you have a good condition to start `setTimer()`, your code should look more like this:

```
var timer;

function autoplay() {
    clearTimeout(timer); //! New code.
    currentPosition++;
    if(currentPosition == numberOfSlides) {
      // last slide
      currentPosition = 0;  
    }
    manageNavigation(currentPosition);

    // Hide / show controls
    manageControls(currentPosition);

    // animate the slides
    slideshowAnimate();  

    // set timer
    setTimer(); //! Switched from having multiple startup locations.
}
function setTimer() { 
    if(autoplay_enable) {
      timer = setTimeout(autoplay, interval*1000);  //! Removed unnecessary closure.
    }
}

setTimer();
```

Comment: I think this code is only semantically different. Changing my original code to something like this keeps Chrome failing after tabchange and returning to the tab at a later stage.

Comment: The only bit that really needs to get added is the clearTimeout.  It sounds like you've got some other issue with your startup state.  I expect all of this is global or wrapped in a single startup closure?

Answer (score 0):

the return of the setTimeout is an index number that is used for internal recognition of the timers, not the actual timer itself. therefore you are only writing over the thing that is pointing to a timer, not removing the timer that is running when you make the timer again.

To save computing power, the chrome engine freezes most javascript running in background tabs, and then seems to try and "catch up" when it gets back in focus. Not sure what the fix would be for this though. definitely use the clearTimeout or better yet use a Timer object to try and catch this as a repetetive action.

Comment: Okay, so it's basically an issue with Chrome? Does 'catching up' means that eventually it will animate as it should?

Comment: there are a few comments on the dev channel here: http://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/group/chromium-dev/browse_thread/thread/ff827011f2d1f0f6 that might be of interest, but the throttling seems to be 1sec per call which should be fine. it might be the animation transition that is killing it, try putting in a boolean for an animation lock or stripping out the animation for a test.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried found a small fix. You can try to add this to your code

```
var timer;
```

...

```
$(window).blur(function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
}).focus(function() {
    timer= setInterval(autoplay, interval*1000);
});
```

Hope this can help.